# view SQLite Databases in android listview?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-listview

I am sure there is an easy solution to this one but I figured I would check with all the folks here first.

I am working on a database creation and management application for android where the user creates and manages data along the line of what PHPMyAdmin does for regular computers.

I have the section where the user creates a database and can insert tables with the appropriate styled data into the system.

The next priority is selecting which DB to enter and modify its contents.  Is there a way to display the available databases, along with its table contents, in the form of a list-view for the user to enter and edit the desired data??

I know that this is a rather dull question, but this is basically the last piece of the puzzle for me to fit into this app before it is operational in a raw format.  If you need any further information, or any code to examine, I will be happy to provide.

Thanks again for everyone's assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good tutorial on SQLite databases and displaying contents in a `ListView`:
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html#databasetutorial

It doesn't go over editing that much, but it's easy to see where he puts the values into the database.

thenewboston on YouTube is a good resource for Android tutorials and he goes over `SQLite` databases:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gEg9OdufXmM

It's pretty comprehensive and slow if you already kinda know what you're doing so here is where he goes over inserting data/editing the database if you just wanna jump to that:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S3Z4e7KgNdU

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions.  I have indeed watched thenewboston on sqlite and have a fair understanding of how to make the commands and user-updates.  As I mentioned, what i am looking for is how to view all available databases in a listview.

Comment: That would probably go along the lines of exploring the folder where you made all the databases and getting their file names and putting them into a listview similar to what the tutorials are doing with contents of the database, then opening the db that the user selects.

Comment: So is that something along the line of an inputStream jumping into the app's data file, collecting the names of the DBs and parsing them into a list?

Answer (score -1):

I know this below can be optimized but for now just create such a method to do it automatically. The method...

1. Creates an empty database of a random name for a second,
2. Saves the new database's location - **getDatabasePath**,
3. Quikly deletes the empty database,
4. Removes filename form the saved path to get the directory path olny,
5. List all files in the database path excluding '-journal' files.

And it goes like this:

```
ArrayList<String> arr_list_of_db_files = getDBFILES();

pivate ArrayList<String> getDBFILES() 
  {
   ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>;
   String db_path, rand_name, str_tmp;

   //ad.1-2. random file name for db   
   rand_name = new Random().nextInt((4000000-2000+1)+2000).toString()+".db";
   db_path = openOrCreateDatabase(rand_name, MODE_PRIVATE, null).getPath();

   //ad.3.
   deleteDatabase(rand_name);

   //ad.4.
   db_path = db_path.replace("/" + rand_name, "");

   //ad.5.
   File [] files = new File(db_path).listFiles();
   if (files == null) { return null; }

   //so now we get the filenames one by one
   for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
       { 
          str_tmp = files[i].getName();
          if (!str_tmp.endsWith("-journal"))
             {  arr.add(str_tmp); }
       }
   return arr;
  }
```

Btw, I cant test the code, but I hope it is fine and some of you find it useful.

***Edited: I have optimized the above code.***